# Can't create Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to make a Stored Procedure using the following code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE films
@filmTitle varchar(25)
AS
SELECT *
FROM films
WHERE film_title = @film_title
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL           server version for the right syntax to use near '@filmTitle varchar(25)
AS
SELECT *
FROM films
WHERE film_title = @film_title' at line 2
```

What is going wrong? I can't figure it out.

Also I tried to make a Stored Procedures via the routines in Phpmyadmin but whenever i execute the code it returns nothing

This is the configuration of my routine:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjgUE.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `films` (IN p_filmTitle VARCHAR(25))
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM films
WHERE film_title = p_filmTitle;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```